# Why do questions like this get closed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, closed-questions, close-reasons, reopen-closed

Looking at this question: [Improve INSERT-per-second performance of SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1711631/89771)

I don't see the motivation for closing it. The aggregated knowledge in the question itself clearly shows that the question was specific enough to be answered in the current form. Furthermore, it's not incomplete (perhaps a bit outdated due to it being closed / locked) nor broad or rhetorical.

I find the findings / solutions incredibly valuable.

Here are a couple of very similar questions (most of them more ambiguous) that weren't closed:

- [What are the performance characteristics of sqlite with very large database files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/784173/89771)
- [What is the fastest way to insert 100 000 records from one database to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2124991/89771)
- [SQLite insert speed slows as number of records increases due to an index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15778716/89771)

So, why?

Comment: So, we should close similar questions if they're not real questions too.

Comment: @MM.: What? How are any of those not *real* questions?

Comment: The first two you link are 3+ years old, and are probably preserved because of historical significance. (Guidelines here change over time as new SE sites develop, and those two have high votes from when they were appropriate here.) The third should in fact be migrated to [dba], as it's more appropriate there than here (and it's far too broad in scope as well) IMO.

Comment: It hard to judge about many question, but the mechanism allowed us to undo a decision, if you think it's a bad idea to close a question, you can vote to reopen.

Comment: @MM.: I did - a couple of months ago. And it's still 3 votes away from being reopened.

Comment: Maybe people who see it in the reopen queue actually read it and notice it's a blog post, not a question.

Comment: @KenWhite: My frustration is with the first link (there are four). I've been on StackOverflow for nearly 5 years now, and I don't recall any guideline that would provide motivation to close such a well formulated, complete and useful question.

Comment: @Wooble: That's a valid point I can understand. But I guess [it turned into a blog post](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4716bfb4-2376-4fdc-b9bb-1dde732be0cd/view-source) after aggregating the knowledge and experiments from all the answers. I don't see what's wrong with that. Am I required to post a new question with the same exact same title if I want to gather updated input from techniques related to newer versions of SQLite?

Comment: @AlixAxel: You also cited the other three as examples that stayed open, and I explained why I felt they had been. (I think that if any of them had been posted under current guidelines, they would have been closed/migrated as well.) Having looked at the first link, it's not a question and should be closed. It's a blog post, and this is not a personal blogging site. If it had been posted in portions as answers to specific questions (which could have been linked to each other for some continuity), it would be much more appropriate for SO.

Comment: @KenWhite: I get that argument. But by creating a blog-like post the OP was merely aggregating/experimenting with the solutions suggested in the answers. Still, if I wanted to fix it (turn the question into just a question, and the experimentation / results into individual answers) I couldn't do it as the question is locked and no new answers are accepted. On the other side, such a prominent question (has a very high SERP relevance) is "hijacking" related but updated (SQLite 3.8/4.0) separate questions or new solutions from being posted.

Comment: @AlixAxel: I don't understand your confusion here. SO (and the other SE sites) are **question and answer** sites. You cannot post an answer without there first being a question. These are not "ask a question and get an answer, or post a blog entry to share your knowledge" sites. Question and answer is quite clear, and is spelled out very specifically in the help and about pages for every site on the SE network. If people want to post blog entries, they should start a blog and do so. There are plenty of sites available for those types of things; SO isn't one of them.

Comment: @KenWhite: I feel like you almost haven't read what I wrote. I'll sum it up: **1)** I agree with you, but, it didn't start as a blog-like post, and (since it did) **2)** we cannot turn the blog-like content into individual answers and restore the question-like dignity of the original post due to it being closed.

Comment: @AlixAxel: OK. I feel the same (that you're not reading what everyone here is saying, including me), so I guess we're even. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite: Hehe, meta doesn't like me (and vice-versa I guess). Thanks for your time trying to explain it to me though. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really see a compelling reason to reopen the question you linked.  The question, and all of the answers, are Community Wiki; anyone with a reasonable amount of rep can edit it, if it needs updating.   I don't think it needs any new answers.  And the fact that most of the information is in the question is an implementation detail; it doesn't really have any bearing on the veracity of the information.

To answer your direct question, the post was closed because it's a bit too broad for the Q&A format.

Comment: I can accept that. So I assume that the "question" will eventually get deleted if not fixed, correct?

Comment: Not necessarily.  Many closed questions stay on the site indefinitely, if they're still useful in some way.

Answer (score 1):

First question asks how to improve very specific scenario. It's similar to shopping questions as it does not invite answers that describe how to investigate problem and choose solution, but gives very narrow conditions and asks for definitive "to-do" list.

Performance characteristics is something that can be measured with several variables in mind. It would be an answer usable for many, and far from shopping question problem.

"What is the fastest way to insert 100 000 records" while not brilliant and bit broad, also invites more general and widely usable, less shopping-like answers, and it is old, so maybe back then it was OK and later no one bothered to close it.

"SQLite insert speed slows as number of records increases due to an index" is again a scenario that is pretty general, and not bound by 3 screens of conditions.

Comment: I'm only talking about the first question (as the others are not closed). But I have to largely disagree with you, from own experience I can tell you that most of the answers provide solutions that benefit SQLite performance in nearly all scenarios. I don't see where you see the huge specificity in the first question that is not present to a degree in the other questions.

Comment: @AlixAxel if *answers* are good, it does not mean *question* should be reopened. It may mean question should be *edited*, and then reopened. It is possible to provide good answer to bad question, but that does not make question any better.

Comment: Furthermore, there are **plenty** of very, very specific questions (those that only benefit one or two users maybe) being asked on StackOverflow all the time and I don't see nearly 10% of them being closed. I suppose this is due to exposure, but why penalize a question with so many views and upvotes (a metric of usefulness, one might argue)?

Comment: @AlixAxel your last comment is actually about review queue that grew out of control, and it was discussed many many times. The fact that some questions never make it to get reviewed is no proof they are good. I agree that the fact that popular questions are closed faster than unpopular is bad, but the problem is on the "unpopular" side.

Comment: In the *current* form, do you think the question is not good enough for StackOverflow? It may be a bit lenghty, but it provides background (that lots of other SQLite intensive users share) as well as specific testing data, code and solutions. The objective is also clearly stated. Granted, the question might have become a bit long, but that doesn't lower it's quality IMHO.

Comment: @AlixAxel question that provides solutions can't be good on Q&A site. Simple as that. Solutions should be in answers, or it will not be a real question. Just as the close reason says.

Comment: Really?! It seems that the solutions were not provided by the OP, rather aggregated (with added useful benchmarks) from the all the answers others provided. As a solution-seeker, I certainly appreciate that as it saves me time. Oh well, can't fight the system. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @AlixAxel If we would agree that only OP contribution matters, "edit and reopen" button would make no sense in the reopen review queue... As I see it, what is in it should matter, nothing else, and if OP disagrees with current shape, he can make a post CW or ask for disassociation.

Comment: Not sure if I get what you're saying, but I **don't** agree that only the OP contribution matters. IMO, the (now not-increasingly) value comes from the individual answers, and the OP did nothing more than a service to the community of aggregating that knowledge. Read my comment to @KenWhite why I think this is a deadlock that doesn't benefit anyone.